# convert xml data into json in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Need help to convert xml response data into json value and fetch a value from JSON object.

My current code is:

```
const soapRequest = require('easy-soap-request');
const fs = require('fs');
var convert = require('xml-js');

// example data
const url = 'https://sentro.com/ws/apf/ticketing/Gateway?WSDL';
const sampleHeaders = {
  'user-agent': 'sampleTest',
  'Content-Type': 'application/html;charset=UTF-8',
};
const xml = fs.readFileSync('Auto_query_request.txt', 'utf-8');

// usage of module
(async () => {
  const { response } = await soapRequest({ url: url, headers: sampleHeaders, xml: xml, timeout: 1000 }); // Optional timeout parameter(milliseconds)
  const { headers, body, statusCode } = response;
  console.log(headers);
  //console.log(body);
  const options = {ignoreComment: true, alwaysChildren: true};
  var result = JSON.parse(convert.xml2json(body, options));
  console.log(result);
})();
```

When i executed above code , i am getting response like below.

```
{"declaration":{"attributes":{"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8"}},"elements":[{"type":"element","name":"env:Envelope","attributes":{"xmlns:env":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/","xmlns:wsa":"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"},"elements":[{"type":"element","name":"env:Header","elements":[{"type":"element","name":"wsa:MessageID","elements":[{"type":"text","text":"urn:5C8DC410D18D11EABFB75749E02F1482"}]},{"type":"element","name":"wsa:ReplyTo","elements":[{"type":"element","name":"wsa:Address","elements":[{"type":"text","text":"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous"}]},{"type":"element","name":"wsa:ReferenceParameters","elements":[{"type":"element","name":"instra:tracking.compositeInstanceCreatedTime","attributes":{"xmlns:instra":"http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0"},"elements":[{"type":"text","text":"2020-07-29T06:19:25.981-05:00"}]}]}]},{"type":"element","name":"wsa:FaultTo","elements":[{"type":"element","name":"wsa:Address","elements":[{"type":"text","text":"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous"}]},{"type":"element","name":"wsa:ReferenceParameters","elements":[{"type":"element","name":"instra:tracking.compositeInstanceCreatedTime","attributes":{"xmlns:instra":"http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0"},"elements":[{"type":"text","text":"2020-07-29T06:19:25.981-05:00"}]}]}]}]}
```

with the above results its very difficult for me to fetch data from JSON object.

So i need convert this xml body with proper JSON object as below.

```
{
"Header": {
"MessageID": "urn:45597DC0D1B511EA8F1C35236A977E2C",
"ReplyTo": {
"Address": "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous",
"ReferenceParameters": {
"tracking.compositeInstanceCreatedTime": "2020-07-29T11:05:06.880-05:00"
}
},
"FaultTo": {
"Address": "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous",
"ReferenceParameters": {
"tracking.compositeInstanceCreatedTime": "2020-07-29T11:05:06.880-05:00"
}
}
},
"Body": {
"processResponse": {
"payload": {
"RfcProject": {
"IntegrationStatus": "Query - Success",
"Id": "something query",
"Created": "2020-06-16T10:24:18",
"CreatedBy": "something",
"Updated": "2020-07-23T14:14:03",
"UpdatedBy": "somevalue",
"ProjectNum": "something",
```

and also how to fetch value from JSON Value .Can anyone help here

Comment: I don't see any XML in your examples

Comment: The xml data i have already converted in JSON format , but the result is not fair to fetch the value. Is there any better way to convert this into proper JSON

Comment: @Vijay can you post the raw xml? I can help give you an example